# White knots and blue knots -Techeiles

Tags: tzitzis, techeles

On Ptil Techeles's website they bring the opinion of the Baal Haitur [Shaar Tzitzis](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37641&st=&pgnum=60&hilite=) (right column) which says the following :

זמן שהיה התכלת מצוי היו אלה הח’ חוטין ד’ תכלת וד’ לבן ומתחיל וקושר בלבן וכורך חוליא אחד כדי שיכרוך וישנה וישלש וקושר נמצא שהיה בין הקשרים ה’ של לבן וג’ של תכלת .‏

How does one tie a white knot separate from the blue strings aren't all the strings together? Does anyone have a picture or a method to tie like this?

Comment: This is what Ptil Tekhelet has http://www.tekhelet.com/diagrams/BaalHaIturTyingDiagram2.pdf http://tekhelet.com/he/baal-haitur-binyamin-zeev-words/ Note the knot might not be a double knot like you're used to. Take a look at the common "Rambam" style ties to see what I mean.

Comment: I saw all that already, but from his words it seems there is a special type of tying with just white and with just blue

Comment: It seems like Ptil came up with their own way in the Itur

Comment: Sam, I use the Ittur's knots on my tzitzit to beautify the mitzvah. To do so, I separate the strings first, so that all of the techeilet strings are grouped together and all of the white ones are similarly grouped. Then I tie a double knot as we are used to seeing on tzitzit.

Comment: צריך לומר חמש של לבן וארבע של תכלת

Comment: Sorry for being late to the party. See http://www.tekhelet.com/diagrams/IturBlueWhiteMethod/page1.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly simpler version of kouty's answer, written as someone who uses these knots.

What I do is to take all of the blue strings and all of the white strings (the 'Ittur holds like the Tosafot that the blue and white strings appear in equal number) and group them by colour. While this is a bit weird at first (as the strings are from both sides of the hole, rather than the typical grouping found in tzitzit) it is easy enough to figure out visually, and is tied identically to the regular knots, alternating sides so as to alternate the colours of the knot.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: `How does one tie a white knot separate from the blue strings aren't all the strings together?`

A: He makes a double knot between two white areas, 1.- the cloth, 2.- the white Chulia, but **the knot itself is not white**.

The text of the Itur is very hard to understand, but concerning the question, may be that we can add some knowledge.

> **רב ירמיה מדפתא**  עביד תמניא מינייהו שתסיר ולא אביק להו נותן שמונה חוטין בתוך הטלית וכופלן כמו שאנו עושין בארבעה וגדיל אחד בגדיל וענף
>
> **מר בריה דרבינא**  עביד כדידן וכך אנו עושין
>
> וזהו פסק עשייתו מתוך הלכה. טוה הצמר לשם ציצית משלו או משניתן לו במתנה ושוזרם לשנים וסירך מאותו חוט בגודלו פעמיים ושלש ומותח ארבעה אצבעותיו כדי שיהא שיעור ארכן ארבעה אצבעות  גדולים וכורך על ארבע אצבעותיו ומתוחות מאותו החוט  הכרוך בגודל ארבעה ארבעה פעמים ומפסקן נמצא חוטין שהן כפולין כשיעור ארבעה אצבעותיו מתוחות והראשון כרוך על הגודל בתחילה ארוך מן השלשה כדי  לכרוך בו הגדיל ותוחבן במחט **בשני נקבים בטלית** ומטיב ראשיהן בתוכן ראש אחד בנקב אחד והשני בנקב אחד וכופלן והן שבעה חוטין שוין באורך ארבעה אצבעות והאחד עודף עליהן ארוך מכאן ומתחיל וקושר קשר סמוך לטלית  ‏
>
> ‏ ובזמן שהיה התכלת מצוי היו אלה השמונה חוטין ארבעה תכלת וארבעה לבן ומתחיל  **וקושר בלבן וכורך חוליא אחת כדי שיכרוך וישנה וישלש וקושר** 
>   ‏<sup>(1)</sup>‏ נמצא שהיה **בין הקשרים *חמישה* של לבן ‏(‏ *ושלשה* ‏ ) ‏  ‏[‏ צריך לומר ארבעה ‏]‏  של תכלת.**
>
> ‏ ***‏ומסקינן לן עכשיו שאין תכלת והכל לבן*** אין לנו היכר חוליות ונהגו לעשותן **קשרים כנגד חמישה ‏ <sup>(2)</sup> ‏  שהיו בלבן:** שנים סמוך לטלית ושלשה בסוף הגדיל ‏ <sup>(3)</sup> ‏ וכורך ושונה וגודל ארבעה חוטין בחוט הארוך ‏ <sup>(4)</sup> ‏ עד שיהא שליש גדיל ושני שלישי ענף ובשם רבינו חננאל כתב שלשה קשרים למעלה ושנים למטה ומר רב יהודאי איפכא ואותן שנהגו שלש למעלה ושנים בסוף הגדיל יפה עושין שאם יפסק החוט הגדול בסופו ישתייר חוליא אחת סמוך לטלית ובחוליא אחת גדיל כשרה . ‏
>
> ויש מקומות שעושין שבע כריכות וקושר עד שמשלים שבעה קשרים ומנחי סימני שבעה שבועות ואפשר שנהגו מפני "הפוחת לא יפחות משבעה" ומנהג שלנו כמר יהודאי זכרונו לברכה ומנהג בכל שבעה  קשרים למעלה וכורך שבעים כריכות כנגד שבעים פרים ואחר קושר שני קשרים. ורבותינו פירשו טעם חמישה קשרים להשלים תרי"ג מצוות לפי ששלשה פעמים כתוב בפרשה ציצית חסרים יו"ד וכתוב והיה לכם לציצית וגרעון למ"ד ומוסיפים חד על שלשה הכתוב והן כולם מלאים נמצא עולה שש מאות ושמונה חוטין וחמישה קשרים חמישה תרי"ג ולא פירשו טעם חמישה קשרין למה ואנן כתבינן מאי דסבירא לן דארבעה קשרים של לבן עם קשר הסמוך לטלית ורב עמרם ריש מתיבתא בתשובותיו כך כתב וכך היה גודל אחר קשר התחתון חוליא ועליו חוליא תכלת ועליו לבן וכך עוד שבעה קשרים וקושר קשר העליון ואם רצה מוסיף עד שלש עשרה ואחר שקושר הקשרים העליונים פריד החוטין ומבדילן זה מזה וכן עושה בארבעה כנפותיה. ‏

---

**<sup>(1)</sup>** I think that the pshat is that he make the first double knot to bind the cloth which is generally white, and because the cloth is white, the first chulia must be white.

"8>>>>@@ ||| @@ /// @@ ||| @@ /// @@ ||| @@ /// @@ ||| @@ /// @@ ||| @@<<<<"

/// = Skye Blue Chulia, ||| = White Chulia, @@ double knot, 8 = 2 wholes.

Surrounding the 5 white chuliot we need 6  double knots.
To add the 4 tchelet chuliot we nee to add 4 double knots.

**<sup>(2)</sup>** Nowadays,  without tchelet, said the Itur,  we make 5 double knots to remember the 5 white chuliot, and in the inter knots spaces,  we make 4 white chuliot to remember the tchelet chuliot.

**<sup>(3)</sup>** It is not clear for me these knots are the double knots.

**<sup>(4)</sup>** He explains how to make a Chulia with the long strand, 3 rotations.